# double cannot be derefferenced Java equals method

Tags: java, equals

I am trying to create an equals() method for a class and I am getting the following error for the last three lines of my "if statement": double cannot be derefferenced. modelName and VINumber are inherited properties. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
public boolean equals(FourByFour f){
    boolean status = false;
    if (VINumber.equals(f.VINumber) && 
        modelName.equals(f.modelName) &&
        bayWidth.equals(f.bayWidth) &&
        bayHeight.equals(f.bayHeight) &&
        bayLength.equals(f.bayLength))
    {
        status = true;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Don't try and use `equals` to compare primitive types (e.g. doubles). Use `==`.

Comment: What types are bayWidth, bayHeight, and bayLength?

Comment: primitive types like double can does not have methods

Comment: What @khelwood said. If you're using double as the data type for these variables, then don't use .equals, use == instead.

Comment: bayWidth, bayHeight, and bayLength are all doubles. I was told that if I use the == operator then it will compare the memory location rather than the values stored in memory. Is that true?

Comment: @JonathanMath It is for object types, but it is **not** for primitives like int, double, boolean etc

Comment: You leave out a lot of information, like what is `FourByFour`, what are the types of the members of `f`, and of the variables you compare to them. You also could set a boolean variable directly to the result of the boolean condition without using `if`. You also should follow the naming conventions; `VINumber` is a type name but its use suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code

```
double z=100,x=100;
System.out.println("z == x : "+ (z == x));
Double Z = new Double(z), X = new Double(x);
System.out.println("Z.equals(X) : "+ Z.equals(X)+"\n(Z==X) : "+(Z==X));
```

Output :

```
z == x : true
Z.equals(X) : true
(Z==X) : false
```

I hope this example makes things much clearer.

You can't use `.equals` when using primitives (e.g. double) as the data type.
The only operators that can be used are `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`. 
These will give you the boolean results of the comparisons they represent on the basis of the value of the primitive variable.

However, if you use Autoboxing by using the java wrapper classes for primitive types, then `.equals` will give you the arithmetic comparison of your data types, whereas `==` will compare the variable addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably bayWidth, bayHeight, and bayLength are doubles. doubles are primitives, not reference types, and have no methods. Use [java.lang.Double.compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-) to compare double primitives for equals methods.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can only compare object variable like `String` with .equals

if you look on `.equals` method documentation:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject)
```

Parameters:

**anObject** − the object to compare this String against.

so you can't use this method to compare other primitive datatype like `double`, `float` or `int` because they are not object variables.

you should compare them with `==` operator

or you can use `Double` class constructor to convert `double` primitive type to a `Double object`:

```
Double bayWidthobj = new Double(bayWidth);

Double bayHeightobj = new Double(bayHeight);

Double bayLengthobj = new Double(bayLength);
```